# MySQL: How do I find the average for specific rows?

Tags: mysql

I have a sales table and need to calculate the average call time when a case is met. I'm doing the query for each day of the month.

My query is

```
SELECT AVG(case when (outcome= 'Sale1' or outcome='Sale2') then call_length else 0 end) as avg_call_length
FROM SALES 
WHERE year(call_date)='2018' and month(call_date)='7' and day(call_date)='30'
```

Lets say I have 100 records then avg_call_length is divided by 100 instead of how many records are Sale1 or Sale2. How do I write the correct query?

Comment: Please post your schema, with sample data, and the expected outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `case` and move the condition to the `where`:

```
SELECT AVG(call_length) as avg_call_length
FROM SALES 
WHERE date(call_date) = '2018-07-30'
AND outcome IN ('Sale1', 'Sale2')
```

Note the simpler way of coding the conditions.